# Kivy RelativeLayout vs FloatLayout

Tags: android, python, android-layout, kivy

This is from the documentation of Kivy's relative layout.
https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.relativelayout.html

> Relative Layout:  This layout allows you to set relative coordinates
>   for children. If you want absolute positioning, use the FloatLayout.
>   The RelativeLayout class behaves just like the regular FloatLayout
>   except that its child widgets are positioned relative to the layout.
>   When a widget with position = (0,0) is added to a RelativeLayout, the
>   child widget will also move when the position of the RelativeLayout is
>   changed. The child widgets coordinates remain (0,0) as they are always
>   relative to the parent layout.

I see that the Floatlayout also does the same. In fact, Floatlayout and RelativeLayout both support absolute and relative positioning depending upon whether pos_hint or pos is used.

Also in reality regardless of absolute and relative positioning, the widgets are moved when the position of the layout changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**FloatLayout**: This layout organizes the widgets with proportional coordinates with
the size_hint and pos_hint properties. The values are numbers
between 0 and 1 indicating a proportion to the window size.

[image]

[image]

**Relative Layout**: This layout operates in the same way as FloatLayout does, but the
positioning properties (pos, x, center_x, right, y, center_y, and
top) are relative to the Layout size and not the window size.

The available pos_hint keys (x, center_x, right, y, center_y, and top) are useful
for aligning to edges or centering. For example, pos_hint: {'center_x':.5,
'center_y':.5} would align a Widget in the middle, no matter what the size of
the window is.

Comment: Please refer to my response posted as answer above this